# Обясните почему не работает switch

Tags: java

Допустим у меня есть список (вставил имя только одного человека). Xочу сделать меню с выбором (для краткого обзора кода вставил только 1 пункт)

Когда пользователь введет число 1, должно показать имя, фамилию и баланс на счету.

Когда я ввожу число 1, программа работает, но имя и баланс не показывает.

Фрагмент кода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name;
    int a;
    int opt = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("1");
        HashMap<String,Double> map = new HashMap<>();
        Set<Map.Entry<String,Double>> set = map.entrySet();
        map.put("Джон Вейн", 13.22);
        a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        switch (opt){
            case 1:
                for (Map.Entry<String,Double> me : set) {
                    System.out.println(me.getKey());
                    break;
                }
        }
    } while (opt != 0);
}
```

Comment: Так вы задаете проверку для `opt`, а считываете `a`. Т.е. вместо `a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());` надо `opt = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());`

Comment: Ворон -  Спасибо большое! обидно что сам не заметил.

Answer (score 3):

Число читаете в переменную "a", а проверяете "opt".